# Lookup hyperlink not working in List or Properties view (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

On my parent site, I added a list (A), populated it and then created a document library (B) with a lookup column that is a lookup to a column in said list (A).

Now, when I create an item in the document library, the lookup works fine as expected, but when I click on the lookup column in the library, instead of linking me to the item from List (A), I get a pop up message saying something went wrong and the only thing I get when I click on technical details is a correlation ID.  Searched but can't seem to find any help.  Thoughts?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAGuv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you check ULS log file based on the correlation ID? If no, please check it.

The path of the ULS log file is: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS.

About how to check ULS log:
http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-find-error-messages-with-a-correlation-id-token-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: I am the site admin but not the server admin so I don't believe I have access to get to this info.  Anything else I can try?  I do this all over the site without issue so this is bizarre to me that it won't work here.